# Run script defined in PATH location in the current shell

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a bash script that is located in one of my `PATH` locations. When I run the script it ends with a `cd /some/location` but since the script is run in its own subproccess it doesn't change the location in the shell.

I know I can run the script using `. ./the/script.bash` and can even set that up as an alias but I would like to know if there is a way to get a command run from a script in my `PATH` to execute in the current shell.

--EDIT--

Apparently there was some confusion about my initial question so let me give an exact example.

I have a script called `windows` located at `~/bin/` and my .profile adds `/home/$USER/bin` to my `PATH` environment variable. The script `windows` mounts my windows partition (I dual boot) and then changed directories to the home file on my windows partition. The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

mount_point="/media/$USER/windows"
if ! grep -q "[[:space:]]$mount_point[[:space:]]" /proc/mounts; then
    sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/nvme0n1p3 "$mount_point"
fi
cd "$mount_point"/Users/Justin
```

So now when when I type the command `windows` into my terminal it runs this script, but since the script is not run in the current shell the `cd` does not change my current shells directory.

My question was is there a way to make this run in my current shell (so that when I run the command `windows` it changes my directory) without using an alias to call the script preceeded by a `.`

Comment: Running the script using `. ./the/script.bash` (aka *sourcing* the script) is *exactly* the way to get it to execute in the current shell.

Comment: Why mount it from a script when you can add entry for your window partition into /etc/fstab and it will mount during boot process ?

Comment: If it is in your PATH, you can just do `. windows`. You do not need to type the path to the script for sourcing with `.`. But: You can also start a shell in the script, which would, for most purposes, be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on new information in the OP this answer has been changed.

In your script you need to push the directory you want to end up in when the script finishes:

```
rick@dell:/$ cat /usr/local/bin/windows
pushd /boot/grub > /dev/null
ls
```

When you call the script you must but a dot and space in front of it `.` like this:

```
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:/$ . windows
fonts             grub.cfg   grubenv  locale       zapgrub.cfg
gfxblacklist.txt  grub.cfg~  i386-pc  unicode.pf2
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:/boot/grub$
```

Above is simple example of how calling `. windows` containing the `push` command works instead of calling `windows` containing `cd` command.

For your script you need to change `cd "$mount_point"/Users/Justin` to `pushd "$mount_point"/Users/Justin` and call the script with `. windows` instead of `windows`

Comment: @DavidFoerster It was hard for me to understand exactly what OP was asking. However I see now that SteelDriver in comments below OP has been misled the same way as me. His comment got a +1. I'll delete if necessary my when/if OP clarifies.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have updated the original question with a more precise example. Hopefully this will help clear up exactly what it is that I am asking.

Comment: @blitz1616 Thank you for the clarification in the question. As such I've changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The OP changed the question and I've changed the answer accordingly. Please review your down-vote.

Comment: Thanks for the notification and I agree with your answer. +1